# could some help me to avoid 101 error in below code please

Tags: apex, error

```
trigger removeMember on CampaignMember (after delete) {
  removeMemberOnCampaignMemberHelper.afterdelete(trigger.old);
}
```

---

```
public class removeMemberOnCampaignMemberHelper {
    public static void afterdelete(CampaignMember[] records) {
        for(CampaignMember campMem : records){
            Course_Enrolments__c [] CEN =[select id,student__r.name, Student__c from Course_Enrolments__c  where (Campaign__c=:campMem.CampaignId)  and (Student__c=:campMem.contactid and Lead__c=:campMem.Leadid)];
            delete CEN;    
        }      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A common mistake is that queries or DML statements are placed inside a
>   for loop. There is a governor limit that enforces a maximum number of
>   SOQL queries. There is another that enforces a maximum number of DML
>   statements (insert, update, delete, undelete). When these operations
>   are placed inside a for loop, database operations are invoked once per
>   iteration of the loop making it very easy to reach these governor
>   limits.

Instead, move any database operations outside of for loops. If you need to query, query once, retrieve all the necessary data in a single query, then iterate over the results. If you need to modify the data, batch up data into a list and invoke your DML once on that list of data.

> Note:- An individual Apex request gets a maximum of 100 SOQL queries
>   before exceeding that governor limit. there is a limit of 150 DML
>   operations per request, a governor limit will be exceeded after the
>   150th contact is updated.

In your case, You have written soql query inside a for loop that causes issue. You can eliminate as follow:-

```
public class removeMemberOnCampaignMemberHelper {
    public static void afterdelete(CampaignMember[] records) {
        set<id> CampaignIds = new set<id>();
        set<id> contactids = new set<id>();
        set<id> Leadids = new set<id>();
        for(CampaignMember campMem : records){
            CampaignIds.add(campMem.CampaignId);
            contactids.add(campMem.contactid);
            Leadids.add(campMem.Leadid);                
        }    
        Course_Enrolments__c [] CEN =[select id,student__r.name, Student__c from Course_Enrolments__c  where (Campaign__c=:CampaignIds)  and (Student__c=:contactids and Lead__c=:Leadids)];
            delete CEN;
    }
}
```

In the above code, ids have been stored in a set and later used in the query outside the for loop. This ensures you that you will not hit the query limit. It also eliminated the dml exception that might caused in your code.

Read the best practise to be followed in apex here:-  ["Apex Code Best Practices"](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices)

Comment: Thank you very much Sanket. I am learning Apex. I have searched for the solution. However, I could not figure it out perhaps because I was not searching right. Have a great day.

Answer (score 1):

You've put a [SOQL Query inside a loop](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Best_Practice%3A_Avoid_SOQL_Queries_Inside_FOR_Loops), and as such you're hitting a common Governor Limit. It sounds like you're unfamiliar with these Governor Limits, so I'd recommend [learning more about them](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm). This specific issue is a common pitfall for developers new to Salesforce - so much so that prominent bloggers have [posts dedicated to it](https://www.sfdc99.com/2014/01/20/soql-queries-inside-loops/). I'd recommend reading through these types of blogs to identify other bad habits/ practices before you encounter them.

On a related note (pun intended) - as I type this, I see StackExchange recommends almost a dozen related questions, all of which you could've found if you searched before posting. Please do this next time and you'd have found your answer quicker.

In addition, your description of the error is lacking. '101 error' is not an error type. You'd do well to copy the entire error message when asking for help, rather than simply copying/pasting your code and hoping somebody fixes it for you.